# Users count in every district including 0 count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to find the number of users in every district.

My DB Structure:

```
Table Name : countries
country_id  country_name
1           India
2           Singapore
3           Malaysia
4           United States

Table Name : states
state_id    state_name  country_id
1           Tamil Nadu  1
2           Andhra      1
.
.
.
20          Arizona     4


Table Name : districts
district_id     district_name   state_id
1               Trichy          1
2               Chennai         1
3               Hyderabad       2
.
.
.
100             Phoenix         20

Table Name : user_addresses
user_address_id user_id doorno  street  ... districtName    stateName   countryName     active 
1               1       10      ....    ... Trichy          Tamil Nadu  India           1
2               2       A12     ....    ... Chennai         Tamil Nadu  India           0
3               3       A2      ....    ... Chennai         Tamil Nadu  India           1
4               4       B2      ....    ... Chennai         Tamil Nadu  India           1
5               41      89      ....    ... Phoenix         Arizona     United States   1
```

`user_addresses` table contain more than one address for a user. But only one is active. I need to find number of users in a district and country.

I used this query:

```
SELECT country_name, district_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM districts as d 
LEFT JOIN states as s USING (state_id) 
LEFT JOIN countries as c USING (country_id) 
LEFT JOIN user_addresses as ua on ua.districtName = d.district_name 
WHERE ua.active=1 
GROUP BY ua.district
```

I get all the districts in the `user_addresses` and their count. But still I have some districts in `districts` table for which I need to display the count as 0.

What I get:

```
country_name    district_name   COUNT(*)
India           Trichy          1
India           Chennai         2
United States   Phoenix         1
```

What I need:

```
country_name    district_name   COUNT(*)
India           Trichy          1
India           Chennai         2
India           Hyderabad       0
Singapore       ...             0
Malaysia        ...             0
...             ...             0
...             ...             0
United States   Phoenix         1
```

Comment: Move ua.active=1 from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. When in WHERE you get inner join result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT country_name, district_name, COUNT(ua.active) 
FROM districts as d 
LEFT JOIN states as s USING (state_id) 
LEFT JOIN countries as c USING (country_id) 
LEFT JOIN user_addresses as ua on ua.districtName = d.district_name 
                              AND ua.active=1 
GROUP BY country_name, district_name
```

The general `GROUP BY` rule says:

*If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.*

When `LEFT JOIN`, you usually don't put right side table's conditions in the `WHERE` clause, if you do you get inner join result. Move to `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` result!

Comment: Thanks, but I get count(*) for all as 1, and for chennai 2

Comment: Oops, don't do count(*), do count some column in user_addresses. Edited.

Comment: Yeah thanks, worked now! changed to `COUNT(districtName)`. Thanks for the explanation too!